# Sum of columns from 3 different tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I have tables like Rep_table, Selling, Upgrade and Delivery in SQL Server 2005.

I am trying to get the sum of columns in Selling, Upgrading and Delivery.
Rep_Table has columns Rep_TableID, CommID and MerchantID. 
Selling has SellingID, Rep_TableID, AmountSold, S_AmountCollected,
Upgrading has columns UpgradingID, Rep_TableID, AmountUpgraded, U_AmountCollected
Delivery has columns DeliveryID, Rep_TableID, D_AmountCollected

Rep_Table will have 3 records, 1 each for selling, Upgrading and Delivery. and my goal is to get the sum of Sold and Upgraded, sum of all collected from 3 tables and balance.

When i try this below query, i dont get to see the join working well. This query gives me Selling in 1 row, Upgrade info in 1 row and Delivery in an other row for each Merchant. What i am looking for is that all the calculations should be done and be in 1 row for each Merchant. I hope i am clear with what i am asking. Thank you all in adavance!

```
Select *, isnull(cast(S.AmountSold as numeric(10,2)), 0) + isnull(cast(U.AmountUpgraded as numeric(10,2)), 0) as AmountSold,
isnull(cast(S.S_AmountCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) + isnull(cast(U.U_AmountCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) + isnull(cast(D.D_AmountCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) as AmountCollected,
(isnull(cast(S.AmountSold as numeric(10,2)), 0) + isnull(cast(U.AmountUpgraded as numeric(10,2)), 0)) - 
(isnull(cast(S.S_AmountCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) + isnull(cast(U.U_AmountCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) + + isnull(cast(D.D_AmountCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) ) as Balance

 from Rep_Table RD
inner join Merchant M on M.MerchantID = RD.MerchantID --for MerchantInfo
left outer join SellingInfo S on S.RepInfoID = RD.RepInfoID
left outer join UpgradingInfo U on U.RepInfoID = RD.RepInfoID
left outer join DeliveryInfo D on D.RepInfoID = RD.RepInfoID
where RD.CommuniTeeID = @CommuniTeeID
```

Comment: You need to clarify by what you mean by `not working well`.

Comment: @DanielKelley I updated my question. Sorry for being unclear! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should consider posting your table structures, some sample data and then the desired result or create a sql fiddle with this.  At this point, I think your question will be difficult to answer.

Comment: @Ram No problems. I have added an answer which is my best guess based on the info given.

Answer (score 0):

OK, give the below a shot:

```
Select sum(isnull(cast(S.AmountSold as numeric(10,2)), 0) + isnull(cast(U.AmountUpgraded as numeric(10,2)), 0)) as AmountSold
    , sum(isnull(cast(S.S_AmountCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) + isnull(cast(U.U_AmountCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) + isnull(cast(D.D_AmountCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0)) as AmountCollected
    , sum((isnull(cast(S.AmountSold as numeric(10,2)), 0) + isnull(cast(U.AmountUpgraded as numeric(10,2)), 0)) - (isnull(cast(S.S_AmountCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) + isnull(cast(U.U_AmountCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) + + isnull(cast(D.D_AmountCollected as numeric(10,2)), 0) )) as Balance
from Rep_Table RD
inner join Merchant M on M.MerchantID = RD.MerchantID --for MerchantInfo
left outer join SellingInfo S on S.RepInfoID = RD.RepInfoID
left outer join UpgradingInfo U on U.RepInfoID = RD.RepInfoID
left outer join DeliveryInfo D on D.RepInfoID = RD.RepInfoID
where RD.CommuniTeeID = @CommuniTeeID
group by m.MerchantID
```

I have added a `SUM` to each of your columns (I removed the `*` as it can complicate things) and I added a `GROUP BY` on `m.MerchantID`.